# Storybook Angular: How to use model / interface from imported custom library?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

so I have an Angular App built in an NX workspace and using custom libraries for each re-useable feature.

I have a lib to store the models for the app. It is built using NX workspace. eg.

`nx g @nrwl/workspace:lib dc-models`
This builds and runs fine using **nx serve**  It has no errors.

When I run storybook eg

`nx run dc-featurelib:storybook` It builds but it is displaying Warnings in the terminal saying it cannot find the models.

```
WARNING in ./libs/dc-feature-panel/feature-panel/src/lib/feature-panel/feature-panel.component.ts 33:78-86
"export 'DcPanel' was not found in '@myproject/dc-models'
```

How do I get this working and remove this warning ??

Comment: delete your package-lock.json and then rebuild again

Comment: I will try that and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alexff1  solved it.

`rm -rf node_modules;` then  `npm install`.

After I deleted and re-installed the node modules this fixed the issue.

This was not something I thought of doing as the project has a lot of node modules and takes a long time to install them.
Also 'DcPanel' and '@myproject/dc-models' are not imported modules so re-installing node modules never crossed my mind.

But looks like it worked. Thanks.